# RxSwift create multiple Observable from One

Tags: ios, swift, mvvm, rx-swift

how can I share one API call? For example, I have the following Model class. The properties will bind to different UI components.  I am implementing this in the ViewController. But, I think I should not expose the Model to the View layer. Instead, I should give the ViewController two Observable properties to bind. One is for UITextField, the other is for the UITableView. So, how should I create more than one Observable from an Observable?

```
struct CustomerListJSON : Codable {
    var UserCount:Int?
    var TotalReward:Int?
    var CurMonthUserCount:Int?
    var CurMonthTotalReward:Int?
    var CurYearUserCount:Int?
    var CurYearTotalReward:Int?
    var UserList:[CustomerJSON]?
}

let getSummery = self.viewModel.getSummery()

getSummery.flatMap{ [weak self](summery) ->  Observable<[CustomerJSON]> in

//Label datesource
            self?.summeryLabel.text = " \(summery.UserCount ?? 0)\t \(summery.TotalReward ?? 0)\n \(summery.CurMonthUserCount ?? 0)\t \(summery.CurMonthTotalReward ?? 0)\n \(summery.CurYearUserCount ?? 0)\t\(summery.CurYearTotalReward ?? 0)"

            return Observable.of(summery.UserList ?? [])
//Table datasource
        }.bind(to: self.tableView.rx.items(cellIdentifier: "customerCell", cellType: UITableViewCell.self)){ (index, customer, cell) in
            cell.textLabel?.text = "\(customer.UserName ?? "")\t\t\(customer.CreateTime ?? "")"
        }.disposed(by: rx.disposeBag)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a non-mature solution like this. So, I can bind these two Observable to the UI in the ViewController in order to hide the Model structure.

However, the API call is not able to share. This is another issue~

```
    fileprivate func apiCall() -> Observable<Response> {
                let userID = UserModel.sharedInstance.uID

                return self.dateParameterTrigger
                    .observeOn(self.queue)
                    .flatMap{ para -> Observable<Response> in
                        let startDateStr = para.0
                        let endDateStr = para.1
                        return self.provider.rx.request(CustomerTarget.GetInvitedUserList(userID, 0, 20, startDateStr, endDateStr))
                               .asObservable()
                               .share(replay: 1, scope: SubjectLifetimeScope.forever)
                    }

            }

            func getSummery() -> Observable<CustomerListJSON> {

                return apiCall()
                    .flatMap{ event -> Observable<CustomerListJSON> in
                        let catchReturn = Observable.of(CustomerListJSON())
                        var baseModel:CustomerModel!

                            do{
                                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                                baseModel = try decoder.decode(CustomerModel.self, from: event.data)
                            }catch let error {
                                print( error )
                                return catchReturn
                            }

                            guard let model = baseModel, let customerModel = model.returnValue else {
                                return catchReturn
                            }

                            return Observable.just(customerModel)
                }
            }

            func getCustomerList() -> Observable<[CustomerJSON]> {

                return self.apiCall()
                    .flatMap{ event -> Observable<[CustomerJSON]> in
                        let catchReturn = Observable.of([CustomerJSON]())
                        var baseModel:CustomerModel!
                        do{
                            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                            baseModel = try decoder.decode(CustomerModel.self, from: event.data)
                        }catch let error {
                            print( error )
                            return catchReturn
                        }

                        guard let model = baseModel, let customerModel = model.returnValue, let customerList = customerModel.UserList else {
                            return catchReturn
                        }

                        return Observable.just(customerList)
                }
            }
```